# How to manipulate the output after selecting and ordering TOP RESULT

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE DNWorld
GO

SELECT TOP (100) WITH TIES PvPExp 
FROM PvPRanking
ORDER BY PVPExp DESC

UPDATE PVPRanking
SET PVPLevel = 26 
WHERE TOP(1) = 1
```

ERROR:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server NS544979, Procedure , Line 0
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'.
>   [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'. (156)

I have successfully selected and ordered the PvPExp in the query.

I want to set PVPLEVEL = 26 for the #1 Top result. That isn't working.

Then from that I want to set The #2-#5 Top result a certain value.

So on and so forth. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PVPExp DESC) AS rn
  FROM PvPRanking
)
UPDATE cte
SET PVPLevel = CASE rn
  WHEN 1 THEN 26
  ELSE ?
END  
WHERE rn <= 5
```

Replace `?` with the value that you want to set to *#2-#5 Top* rows.
If you want to set different values for them also:

```
.............................
SET PVPLevel = CASE rn
  WHEN 1 THEN 26
  WHEN 2 THEN ?
  WHEN 3 THEN ?
  WHEN 4 THEN ?
  WHEN 5 THEN ?
END 
.............................
```

Comment: I do have one question if you're still around. Would there be a way to shorten this?

Example

Set PVPLEVEL =  Case rn

When rn between 2 and 10 then 5

Meaning 2-10 get assigned 5

Comment: Check the syntax for this case: `Case When rn = 1 then 26 when rn between 2 and 10 then 5 end`

Comment: But if there is a where clause like: `where rn<=10` then you only need `else`: `Case When rn = 1 then 26 else 5 end`

Comment: Well I'm going to be expanding this list to TOP results at the moment.

I understand the first solution you presented but the syntax didn't work out.

 [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='. (102)

Comment: Check this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c511c8a7f02d0f94b6e3d789e73e428e All the queries are syntactically correct.

Comment: thanks finally resolved it! 


WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PVPExp DESC) AS rn
  FROM PvPRanking
)
UPDATE cte
SET PVPLevel = CASE 
  WHEN rn = 1 THEN 26
  WHEN rn BETWEEN 2 AND 10 THEN 25
  ELSE 17
END  
WHERE rn <= 100

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() with a CTE. ie:

```
with rankings (PvpExp, rowNo) as
(
   SELECT PvPExp, row_number() over (order by PvpExp desc) 
   FROM PvPRanking
)
UPDATE PVPRanking 
   SET PVPLevel = case 
                  when r.rowNo = 1 then 26
                  when r.rowNo > 1 and r.rowNo < 6 then xx
                  -- other settings
                  end
from PVPRanking pr
inner join rankings r on pr.PVPExp = r.PVPExp;
```

What you need might be Rank(), DenseRank() ... instead of row_number() based on your real needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It wasn't the answer that I needed but it helped me understand where I should start and what I should do.